# How to build a table of medians in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have data from multiple questions divided in three groups. I wanted to summarize the medians in a matrix  like this

```r
numQuestions <- c("FB3Q1", "FB3Q3q1", "FB3Q3q2", "FB3Q5", "FB3Q6", "FB3Q7", "FB3Q9", "FB3Q11q1", "FB3Q11q2")

medians <- matrix(nrow = length(numQuestions), ncol = 3,
                  dimnames = list(numQuestions, c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")))
for(i in rownames(medians)){
  for(j in c(1:3)){
    medians[i,j] <- median(paste0("results",j,"$",i))
  }
}
```

Here `i` is the ID of the questions and `j` the group.

But instead of calculating the medians it just writes the matrix like:

```r
         Group 1             Group 2             Group 3            
FB3Q1    "results1$FB3Q1"    "results2$FB3Q1"    "results3$FB3Q1"   
FB3Q3q1  "results1$FB3Q3q1"  "results2$FB3Q3q1"  "results3$FB3Q3q1" 
FB3Q3q2  "results1$FB3Q3q2"  "results2$FB3Q3q2"  "results3$FB3Q3q2" 
FB3Q5    "results1$FB3Q5"    "results2$FB3Q5"    "results3$FB3Q5"   
FB3Q6    "results1$FB3Q6"    "results2$FB3Q6"    "results3$FB3Q6"   
FB3Q7    "results1$FB3Q7"    "results2$FB3Q7"    "results3$FB3Q7"   
FB3Q9    "results1$FB3Q9"    "results2$FB3Q9"    "results3$FB3Q9"   
FB3Q11q1 "results1$FB3Q11q1" "results2$FB3Q11q1" "results3$FB3Q11q1"
FB3Q11q2 "results1$FB3Q11q2" "results2$FB3Q11q2" "results3$FB3Q11q2"
```

It is kinda obvious that I am missing a function to make a command of the string I get from the `paste0()` call, but I couldn't find out what it is, yet.

Comment: Study `help("$")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below

```r
sapply(
  setNames(list(results1, results2, results3), c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")),
  function(v) miscTools::colMedians(v[numQuestions], na.rm = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: I think `sapply()` is part of what I need, however I only get `NA` in the matrix from this

Comment: Found my mistake: there were some `NA` fields in the dataframe. By adding the `na.rm` argument to the function I got what I wanted. I edited it in your answer already. Thank you!

Comment: @skranz Yes, if you have `NA` values, you should have option `na.rm = TRUE` there. I have accepted your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in R, but i think that working with strings to call objects isn't ideal. A better way would be have the 3 `results` objects together in one - maybe by doing `results = list(results1, results2, results3)` - and then changing your loop to:

```
for(i in rownames(medians)){
    for(j in c(1:3)){
        medians[i,j] <- median(results[[j]][[i]])}}
```